# Spring data jpa specification criteria with complex class field

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I can write next specification:

```
public static Specification<Order> filterByDriver(Driver driver) {
    return new Specification<Order>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.get(Order_.driver), driver);
        }
    };
}
```

but what if I want to find all orders for driver with name, for example  'Bob'. How can I write something like that:

```
public static Specification<Order> filterByDriverName(String driverName) {
    return new Specification<Order>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.get(Order_.driver.name), driverName);
        }
    };
}
```

I am using spring-data-jpa: 1.8.0.RELEASE, please help and thanks.

Comment: @OliverGierke can you take a look at this one? :) I'm searching for hours the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `return cb.equal(root.get(Order_.driver.name), driverName);` with `return cb.equal(root.get("driver").get("name"), driverName);`

If you want to search for a string regardless of it's position in the exact name you should use

```
cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("driver").get("name")), ("%" + driverName + "%").toLowerCase())
```

Complete solution (equal):

```
public static Specification<Order> filterByDriverName(String driverName) {
return new Specification<Order>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.equal(root.get("driver").get("name"), driverName);
    }
};
```

}

With like expresion:

```
public static Specification<Order> filterByDriverName(String driverName) {
return new Specification<Order>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("driver").get("name")),  ("%" + driverName + "%").toLowerCase());
    }
};
```

}

I don't know the solution with metadata because I didn't use it so far. I know that is not type safe but at least it solves the problem.

Please try root.get(Order_.driver).get(String_.name) and let us know if this works. I can't test this now that's why I'm asking you to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is:

```
public static Specification<Order> filterByDriverName(final String driverName) {
    return new Specification<Order>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.get("driver").get("name"), driverName);
        }
    };
}
```